# How to set default namespace for T4 generated code

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, t4

So, I have f T4 template stored in folder ProjectRoot/Data, and every time I rebuild my project, this template also gets rebuild and so VS automatically sets namespace for the generated class to ProjectName.Data, but all of my other classes are stored in namespace ProjectName, so this makes a problem because I don't want to change this namespace each time I rebuild project or template, especially if I will share this project with others, so are there any functionality to set a namespace for generated code inside T4 code itself?

**EDIT**

Here is the minimal reproductive example of this problem:

*File Output.tt, located in ProjectRoot/Data*

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="GLGenerator" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>

// Some other code

<#+

    // Public constructor & class properties here

#>
```

And then auto-generated class based on this .tt file looks like this:

```
namespace <ProjectRoot>.Data
{
    using GLGenerator;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System;

    public partial class OutputEnums : OutputEnumsBase
    {
        public virtual string TransformText()
        {
            // Auto-generated template code
        }

        // Class properties & constructor    
    }
    // Other auto-generated code.        
}
```

And as you can see, VS automatically sets namespace for this class to ProjectName.Data, which is bad for me as I want to have all of my classes in one namespace to make most of them internal for this namespace. So, is there a way to change this behavior of VS to something else?

Comment: Why not add `namespace MyNamespace {` to the tt?

Comment: Won't it just put this text into resulting string? Or do you mean something else, because I want to have that auto-generated class to be placed in some namespace.

Comment: It seems I don't get your problem. The t4 just generates a text file, it is completely under your control what it contains.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but at build time VS generates C# class from this T4 template, and this class is stored in wrong namespace for me, so I'm looking for some way to change that default namespace to something else.

Comment: Could you please provide a concrete [mcve]?

Comment: Added that in the last edit.

Comment: If I transform your tt, I don't get the result you posted.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion taking place in the comments seems to be that @Klaus assumes the use of a simple template that generates the *output* (a class) directly. But the question is about a runtime template that generates an *intermediary* class (with undesired namespace), which then generates the output (another class) at runtime.

Given this understanding, the solution is to right click the `.tt` file, click on "Properties", then choose "Custom Tool Namespace".

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class OutputEnums
    {
        public virtual string TransformText()
        {
            // Auto-generated template code
<#
#>
            return "";
        }

        // Class properties & constructor    
    }
    // Other auto-generated code.        
}
```

It produces - as expected -

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class OutputEnums
    {
        public virtual string TransformText()
        {
            // Auto-generated template code
            return "";
        }

        // Class properties & constructor    
    }
    // Other auto-generated code.        
}
```

Comment: Your T4 file looks a bit weird, in this form it will just produce C# script that simply prints its content into a resulting string, that's not what I meant in question. My problem was that when I build the project, T4 also gets built and namespace of that created class is not what I need, so I'm looking for some way to change this VS behavior or manually set namespace for generated class.

Comment: That's because I did not write anything between <# and #>

Comment: Yes, but I had to write code between <# and #>, and then class, that was generated on this template, not file, but class is stored in wrong namespace.

Comment: As I wrote in a comment to your question: "If I transform your tt, I don't get the result you posted". It is extremely hard to guess what your real problem is without a reproducible example.